# SQLServerException:The statement did not return a result set. Can i remove result?

Tags: java

How i can run the query without getting the throw message `SQLServerException:The statement did not return a result set`.Can i run in it without result ? Cause that i want is just to run the query and copy my values from one table and add them  to another with one query

```
 public void makesales(){

         Connection con =getConnection();
         Statement st;
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         ResultSet rs;
     try{
         String query= "INSERT INTO Sales (Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity,Pro_Price ) SELECT Pro_Id,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity ,Pro_Price FROM Receipt";
         pst=con.prepareStatement(query);

                        rs=pst.executeQuery();
                      if (rs.rowInserted()){
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "copy success");
                      }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");                      }
                        // if (rs.next()){

                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"done");
                       //  }else{
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "wrong");
     //}

     }catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); }



     }
```

Here is the correct code for someone that want to use it..

```
     public void makesales(String query,String message) {


        Connection con =getConnection();
        Statement st;
        try{
            st =con.createStatement();
            if((st.executeUpdate(query))==1)
            {            
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
            }

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}


private void ReceiptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        String query= "INSERT INTO Sales (Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity,Pro_Price ) SELECT Pro_Id,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity ,Pro_Price FROM Receipt";
    makesales(query,"Inserted");
}
```

Comment: i thing your post is helpful but i can't make it work.. any suggestions

Comment: "I can't make it work" is much too vague. Ask another question, with the new code, the expected behavior, and thz actual behavior (error message, exception stack trace, etc.)

Comment: my code is working in my sqlserver the values are copying from one table to another but i get catch (Exception e)SQLServerException:The statement did not return a result set. Can i remove result? thats my problem that i dont want to get this message

Comment: As in the linked question, don't use `executeQuery` for updates. Use `executeUpdate` instead.

Comment: so i remove try catch ? and change executeQuery to pst.executeUpdate ?